# blank page with internet explorer 8 and vaadin

Tags: internet-explorer-8, vaadin

A vaadin application shows allways as blank page. The debug output shows a

JavaScriptException: (TypeError): Objekt erwartet number: -2146823281 description: Objekt erwartet
Processing time was 31ms for 1877 characters of JSONReferenced paintables: 8

"Objekct erwartet" means "Object expected".

This happens with every IE8 in company, not with FireFox. It runs on a Tomcat 7 server. Working and temp directories have been cleared. Meanwhile, tomcat has been completely removed and reinstalled. Caches have been cleared. ?restartApplication was called.

The same war-file on a tomcat of an other machine works.

Any idea what the problem may be? Or how I can get deeper into the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what's going on in the IE's soul, but you may try IETester program (free) and use the DebugBar tool (http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage). Maybe you find some clue in the HTTP(s) tab in the DebugBar. Good luck!

Ps: scripts and other security settings are OK and allowed in IE?

Comment: i think only solution should be as answer, this can be as comment

Comment: just like you did for this answer

Comment: Sorry, but i haven't comment option at the question, probably i haven't reached the necessary reputation level...